# Launcher missing when switched to Desktop from a full screen video

Tags: 16.04, video, launcher, fullscreen

When I switch to Desktop using <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>tab</kbd> while watching a full-screen video (Any player / Youtube) My Launcher and the top panel vanishes. Even Right-click won't work.

Example :

My Desktop Before :

[image]

Watching any Full-screen Video :

[image]

I switch to Desktop using <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>tab</kbd> :

[image]

Then I find **launcher and Top panel missing** :

[image]

---

For clear understanding , I have made a video. Please check here : **https://youtu.be/M9TforHAY3g**

Comment: Yup, I have the same issue.

Comment: As it was found that multiple users are facing this problem, I have reported this as bug . Link : https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/1593553 . If you have the same problem, please mark it as "Tes, it affects me"